# Docker CMD and Mount exclude each other

Tags: docker

1. **Usecase**: I have a small dot.net core sdk 3.0 application which should run inside a container.
2. **Usecase**: I will also mount a container folder to a windows file system

The Dockerfile for the image looks like:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0

#SET WORKING DIRECTORY
WORKDIR /app

#COPY ALL AND RESTORE
COPY . .
RUN dotnet restore "Modeling\\ModellingMicroServices.sln"

#INSTALL SOFTWARE
SHELL ["cmd", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]
RUN Start-Process 'software\\graphviz-2.38.msi' '/qn' -PassThru | Wait-Process;

#CMD SDK3.0
CMD ["Modeling\\MicroServiceModelCompilerCore\\bin\\Debug\\netcoreapp3.0\\MicroServiceModelCompilerCore.exe", "watcher", "Modeling\\MicroServiceModelCompilerCore\\bin\\Debug\\netcoreapp3.0"]
```

Seperated **U1** and **U2** works fine.

#### U1:

```
docker build -t mms .
docker run --name mms-c mms
```

#### U2:

```
docker build -t mms .
docker run -d --name mms-c --mount type=bind,source="C:/Users/user/Desktop/ModellingMicroServices/mount",target="C:/app/Modeling/MicroServiceModelCompilerCore/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.0" mms
```

---

#### Problem:

**U2** only works when I don't call the `CMD` command at the end of the dockerfile. If the I don't do this, the `docker run -d --name mms-c --mount` command returns:

```
9dd272dec48731982bebffa884a1a6eb81e211763b390eeb18f411781521d5a7
docker: Error response from daemon: container 9dd272dec48731982bebffa884a1a6eb81e211763b390eeb18f411781521d5a7 encountered an error during CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The system can not find the stated file. (0x2)
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
[Event Detail: onecore\vm\compute\management\orchestration\vmhostedcontainer\processmanagement.cpp(173)\vmcomputeagent.exe!00007FF6157B9D2B: (caller: 00007FF61576E13A) Exception(4) tid(3a0) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    CallContext:[\Bridge_ProcessMessage\VmHostedContainer_ExecuteProcess]
```

Comment: In the second case, it looks like you're mounting the volume over the directory that contains the application; that will hide everything that's in the image.  What's actually in the mounted folder?  Can you choose a different directory in the container to hold it?

Comment: Thats correct and it makes totally sense, I will change the container target directory. Thanks for that answer!

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to add the name of the app ?

Like this :

```
docker run -d --name mms-c --mount type=bind,source="C:/Users/user/Desktop/ModellingMicroServices/mount/MicroServiceModelCompilerCore.exe",target="C:/app/Modeling/MicroServiceModelCompilerCore/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.0/MicroServiceModelCompilerCore.exe" mms
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I only need to mount the directory of the application. Not the application it self. I reproduce this usecase in a super simple command line application and it works like charm. Created files from the container get exchanged to the file system. In this case the files that created in `C:/app/Modeling/MicroServiceModelCompilerCore/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.0` should get exchanged.